# List of Texture2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple game that need to capture a photo from the webcam every time the user click on some object. To avoid lag issues because of the task of convert the Texture2D to PNG and write the image on the disk, I am trying to store one List of Texture2D from the captures, and after the game ends, write all on the disk.

The problem is, when I capture one `Texture2D texture` from the webcam and try to do a `List.Add(texture)`, all the elements of the list are updated because it store the reference of `texture`, not the Texture itself. Can anyone please, suggest me one alternative to store all the textures?

Edit: inserting code.

```
public class GetPhoto : MonoBehaviour
{
WebCamTexture webcam;
Texture2D photo;
List<Texture2D> photos;

IEnumerator TakePhoto()
{
    //run when user click on object.
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    photo.SetPixels(webcam.GetPixels());
    photo.Apply();
    photos.Add(photo);
}
```

}

Comment: What about using a new instance of `Texture2D` for every capture? Hard to tell though without seeing your code

Comment: @derHugo just added the code to the question!

Comment: It's not a matter of references. With SetPixels() you are just overwriting the one texture you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said rather use a new `Texture2D` instance for every press like e.g.

```
IEnumerator TakePhoto()
{
    //run when user click on object.
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    var photo = new Texture2D(yourTextureWidth, yourTextureHeight);
    photo.SetPixels(webcam.GetPixels());
    photo.Apply();
    photos.Add(photo);
}
```

otherwise every entry in your list refers to the exact same `Texture2D` instance => everytime you overwrite the content of that instance.